# Batch export of image collection giving consecutive numbers in filename

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, evi

I want to use consecutive numbers in the name of the exported images from a image collection. I want to filter the MODIS image collection within a specific date range and region for the worst EVI images, rank them accordingly to their statistics and export the worst 5 images with their position in their filename. So the image with the worst EVI-mean value gets the filename `Top 1 worst EVI`, the second worst `Top 2 worst EVI` and so on. So far, I am just able to give all the 5 worst images the name `Top 5 worst EVI`, but I would like to make that more specific.

```
var ModisFiltered = MODIS.filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-05-22').filterBounds(ROI)
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(ROI)});

var maxPixels = 1e9; //Maximum amount of pixels for ee.Reducer calculations
var amountWorstYears = 5;

//Calculate Mean of EVI
var FinalCollection = ModisFiltered.map(function(toSVImean){
  var selectSVIband = toSVImean.select(['EVI']);
  var calculateEVImean = ee.Number(selectSVIband.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: ROI,
    scale: 1000,
    bestEffort: true,
    maxPixels: maxPixels 
  }).values().get(0));

  var addSVI_mean = selectSVIband.setMulti({
    EVI_Mean: calculateEVImean
  })

  addSVI_mean=ee.Image(addSVI_mean)
return addSVI_mean.addBands(toSVImean);
})
print ('Image Collection with EVI Mean:',FinalCollection)

//Sort and Filter for lowest SVI
var select = FinalCollection.select(['EVI']).limit(amountWorstYears, 'EVI_Mean');

//Add amount of requested "worst SVI products" to the properties if each image
var selectionWithNumbers = select.map(function(addAmount){
  return addAmount.set({Position_worst_EVI: amountWorstYears})
});
print('Selection with worst EVIs',selectionWithNumbers)
Map.addLayer(selectionWithNumbers.first());

//Calculate consecutive position numbers (suggestion to provide consecutive numbers)
function CalcRank (current, previous){
  var previousNumber = ee.Number(previous//.getNumber('Position_worst_EVI')
  )
  return current.set({Position_worst_EVI: previousNumber})
  return previousNumber.add(1)
}
var rankedSviImages = ee.ImageCollection(selectionWithNumbers.iterate(CalcRank, 0))
print(rankedSviImages)


//Export Image Collection
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(selectionWithNumbers, "SVI_ImageCollection",{
  name: 'Top{Position_worst_EVI}_worst_SVI_{system_date}',
  scale: 1000,
  region: ROI
});
```

I am trying to solve my problem with an iteration, but as this is something new for me, I do not know how to apply that iteration correctly.

```
//Calculate consecutive position numbers (suggestion to provide consecutive numbers)
function CalcRank (current, previous){
  var previousNumber = ee.Number(previous//.getNumber('Position_worst_EVI')
  )
  return current.set({Position_worst_EVI: previousNumber})
  return previousNumber.add(1)
}
var rankedSviImages = ee.ImageCollection(selectionWithNumbers.iterate(CalcRank, 0))
```

[Here is the GEE Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b6dbe8de9ed80cb134c5d621b713cf97)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off not using a library (geetools) to export your collection. Do it yourself, and you get more control. [This questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348749/is-it-possible-with-gee-to-export-all-the-images-in-an-image-collection/349060#349060) show you how. You can get the index through a second argument in the `forEach()` callback function.

```
collection
  .aggregate_array('system:index')
  .evaluate(function (systemIndexes) {
    systemIndexes.forEach(function (systemIndex, i) {
      print(i) // This is your 0-based index
      var image = collection
        .filterMetadata('system:index', 'equals', systemIndex)
        .first()
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: image,
        description: 'my-image-' + i,
        scale: 10,
        maxPixels: 1e13,
        region: geometry,
      });      
    })
})
```